# Preg_match use for bot

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

i have a bot for daily match. But i can't figure out how it will be exactly replace tags,
for example i have data like this;

```
{"id":"45961","title":"Independien - Sporting Cri","type":"1","flag":"tr","date":"2017-03-17 03:45:00","date":"03\/17\/2017 04:32:55","live":"1"},{"id":"45962","title":"Independien - Sporting Cri","type":"1","flag":"tr","date":"2017-03-17 03:45:00","date":"03\/17\/2017 04:32:55","live":"1"}
```

Code:

```
$connect = sanitize_output(connect("h****"));

preg_match_all('@{"id":"(.*?)","title":"(.*?)","type":"(.*?)","flag":"(.*?)","time":"(.*?)","time":"(.*?)","live":"(.*?)"}@si',$connect,$football_t);   

$id=$football_t[0][0];
$title=$football_t[0][1];
```

vs.

With this use i can't select datas,
I want to do table with foreach but i can't figure out how it will be.

Comment: Don't use a regular expression to parse JSON. Use `json_decode()`.

Comment: @Zeki please delete your question because it is a duplicate and that is a no-no on StackOverflow.  Paul's link is 100% a duplicate which was deliberately created to stop SO getting bloated with duplicate questions like yours.

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_decode()` to parse a JSON string, not a regular expression.

```
$data = json_decode($connect);
$id = $data->id;
$title = $data->title;
```

You also shouldn't sanitize JSON, that may prevent `json_decode()` from parsing it properly.

Comment: Thanks, json_decode what i looking for.